# Getting an error on NextJS app when trying to push to gitHub. I added a long video to my assets, but then deleted it and I'm still getting the error

Tags: github, git-commit, git-push, large-files

This is my error:

```
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (19/19), 203.40 MiB | 4.76 MiB/s, done.
Total 19 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (15/15), completed with 9 local objects.
remote: error: Trace: 4691d95faf15f524b92814567706d1e314616d570159112d082546596cdbfbd3
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File public/assets/demo-vid.mov is 203.54 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To github.com:tmowreen97/idea-web-redesign.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:tmowreen97/idea-web-redesign.git'
```

It's my own repository, I had added a video to my assets and didn't realize it was so long. I tried to commit to github and push, but got this error. Then I deleted the video and tried to push the commit and I'm still getting this error. Please, if anyone could help I'd appreciate it!!!

I manually deleted the file and tried to push again but it's not working.

Comment: GitHub won't let you push that commit, so removing the file in a subsequent won't help, because it doesn't remove that commit from the history. Instead, you need to remove the file from the history itself. If you committed that file in its own commit, reset to the previous commit. If you committed that file as part of a larger commit, you'll have to amend it to remove the big file. And if it's longer ago, you'll have to edit your history from when you added the file.

Comment: Let us know which scenario is yours and we'll be better able to help you.

Comment: @joanis thank you for the response! How can i edit the history to do so? It was part of a larger commit, but nothing too big that I wouldn't mind reversing. I ended up starting over and came across the same problem. Accidentally added files to the folder without realizing, and pushed a commit. So I would love the help in finding a solution